# Relation and most Merge Operation calculation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, merge, set

Suppose `C={1,2,...,100}`. Suppose we have set `A_1 to A_n` `(n<=100)`  and at first we have `A_i={i}.` Relation R with 150 elements on C is given. every time we select one elements from `(a,b) ∈ R` randomly. suppose `a ∈ A_i` and `b ∈ A_j`. if `i not equal to j`, we merge `A_j in A_i`. (i.e: `A_i <-- A_i union A_j`). At most, How many Merge Operations we have?

1) 149

2) 150

3) 99

4) 100

My professor says (4) is true, but i couldent get any idea how we reach this !!!! any learning idea?  Or any Code that i can do some experiment with it?

Edit:
A_j merge in A_i, means Deleting A_j and keep A_i. just i think there is two case occurred.

Comment: "suppose a in A_i and b in A_j". By your description of the merge, the `i` and `j` needn't be unique. Do you mean that the valid `A_i`s always form a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of `{1,...,100}`? If so, wouldn't the number of merges trivially be bounded above my the initial number of sets in the partition? If you start off with a partition into `n` subsets, you can do at most `n-1` merges.

Comment: Sorry but that still doesn't answer my question. Perhaps illustrate with a small example - say `n = 3` or something like that and show a few merge steps.

Comment: maybe you means :  "A (binary) relation R between sets X and Y is a subset of X×Y.  (X×Y is a Cartesian product.)  Thus, a relation is a set of pairs. @Pradhan

Comment: The strange part of your question is how you derive i and j from your choice of (a, b) in R.  Do you actually mean for all (i, j) such that `a ∈ A_i` and `b ∈ A_j` and `i != j`, then we union A_i in A_j?  And each time we choose a random (a, b) in R and do that, which results in a change in any of our sets, then we count that as "a merge?"

Comment: Just  a ∈ A_i, and b ∈ A_j.   if i != J we merge it. exactly i didnt know how we get i, j. @jschultz410

Comment: I understand what a relation is. My question is about your merge operations. When you merge, say, `A_1` and `A_2`, `A_1` becomes `A_1 union A_2`, but what happens to `A_2`? Is it simply deleted? If not, and you pick `(a,b)` equal to `(2,3)`, what do you do with the `2`? Does it imply `A_1` or `A_2`?

Comment: (4) really doesn't make sense as an answer for this problem.  I strongly suspect it's supposed to be (3).

Comment: @Pradhan is it possible to say about your first comment? how you adopt this argument to partition of {1,...,100}?

Comment: @QuestionC how you reach to option C? is it possible add more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the way you define "a merge."

If "a merge" actually means [ A_i <- A_i union A_j ] and [ A_j <- {} ], then the correct answer seems to be 99.

That is because each time you perform a merge, then you empty one of the A_k sets and it can no longer participate in any future merges.  Since you have 100 non-empty sets to begin with, you can only perform at most 99 merges before you only have one set that contains elements and no more merges are possible.

Comment: Updated to make more sense of the problem.

Comment: Would you please add one example? why 149 is not correct?